# Unwanted bones/invisible bones. Don't know how to delete them

Tags: rigging, bones

There are more than 25 bones that I believe I don't need as my rig only has ~20 bones. There's no way I have more than that. and when I select the bones some of them affect the weight paint, Some of them are just there, And it bugs me out because of the extra weight I need to paint away and it also causes me errors and just messy in general when I want to select bones in weight paint and I don't know which one is which. (Some of them have the same name for some reason)

This is what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more information. If you didn't put them there, how were these excess bones added to your rig?

Comment: Those are not bones, but Vertex Groups named after your bones. Assuming you don't need them elsewhere (ie, for a modifier or a particle system), you can safely remove them.

Comment: The duplicate "Left Arm IK Controller" is strange, Blender usually don't let you do that. Maybe there is some invisible characters (space) at the end of the string

Comment: I just cleared the parent from the rig and removed every vertex group and parent it back. Now the count is normal. I also found out the reason after some thinking. The file was very old including experimental rigs, Maybe I forgot to clean it properly and caused it to leave in my rig, The rig that I'm using also has been through some testing on its own.